# Redirect the print to the .txt file in Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x

In short, I would like to redirect the print to the .txt file in Python 3.5
I'm gonna try to explain the problem better with a dummy example:

```
parents= [1,2]
for i in parents:
    print("Parent #{}:".format(i))
    for j in range(3):
        print ('Child: ', j+1)
```

This will print the following:

```
Parent #1:
Child:  1
Child:  2
Child:  3
Parent #2:
Child:  1
Child:  2
Child:  3
```

I would like to be able to write this line by line directly into the file. 
I know how to do this from the command line, but I would prefer to include it in the code.

Answer (score 4):

You can provide `file` argument to `print()` calls. Please, [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

```
with open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print(123, True, 'blah', file=f)
```

By default `file` is [sys.stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdout), which can be changed:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('test.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
print(123, True, 'blah')  # prints to test.txt
```

In the latter case, you can get access to the original standard output file with [sys.__stdout__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.__stdout__).

And, as others indicated, you may just use `write()` method on file objects, but `print()` does have certain extra features which `write()` lacks.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open('file.txt', 'a')
parents= [1,2]
for i in parents:
    f.write("Parent #{}:".format(i) + '\n')
    for j in range(3):
        f.write('Child: ', j+1, '\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: Saying "if you want `print` to write to a file, use `write` instead of `print`" doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @Teepeemm True, although it is an acceptable alternative.